# Testing Various Hypothesis Test for Coefficients in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I know in R it returns for a Multiple Regression it returns hypothesis test for βi=0 but what if you want to test such tests like βi=1. Is there any easy command for this or if not how do you call the coefficents standard error, value of coefficent, degree of freedom of regression so i can use t distribution cdf to calculate p value. I want to do this for a general program to run through multiple data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several packages in R that will allow you to test whether coefficients are different from values other than 0.  For example, https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/FSA/hoCoef.html.  In this case, you'd use:
specify,  bo = 1 in the hoCoef function.

Comment: Thanks do you have any other sources I'm trying to get as much info as possible this seems great though

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sources?  Do you mean other packages or R functions for performing the test?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: You could also use the linearHypothesis function from car package.

Comment: For example, linearHypothesis(lm.yourmodel, "slopeToTest = 1").

Answer (score 2):

While there's packages that do this, it's so simple to do you could write a little function.

This returns p-values for a regression summary in `sl` for a two tailed test against equality to the values in `b0`:

```
testb0=function(sl,b0) {
  slm=sl$coefficients                               #$
  t0=(slm[,1]-b0)/slm[,2]
  pt(abs(t0),sl$df[2],lower.tail=FALSE)
}
```

a test of that function:

```
testb0( summary(lm(dist~speed+I(speed^2),cars)), b0=c(0,1,0) )
```

which returns the three p-values

```
(Intercept)       speed  I(speed^2) 
 0.43415754  0.48308979  0.06820122
```

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know how to call most of those result numbers out of linear regression model in r

Comment: Take a look at `str(summary(lm(dist~speed+I(speed^2),cars)))`. The `str` function is very useful for examining what functions return. In this case, though, `help(summary.lm)` describes what information is returned by the `summary`-function for `lm`-objects, and that makes it much clearer. Many R functions return named lists, which are easy to pull information out of.

Comment: Generally speaking if you're writing functions for these things, it's probably better to use accessor-functions to get the information. So for example `coefficients(sl)` is better than `sl$coefficients` (for example, it will often tend to work if you try to generalize your testing function to other cases than `lm` objects that might not even have a `$coefficients` component - they may still have a `coefficients` accessor-function)